# Deserialize JSON data using JavaScriptSerialIzer in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, excel

I have some JSON data that is sent to the server looking like this,

```
{
    "Summary": [{
        "NewBillers": []
        }, {
        "Bench": [{
            "FirstName": "Thomas",
            "LastName": "Train",
            "HomeStateCode": "NY",
            "DirectorName": "N/A"
        }, {
            "FirstName": "Bill",
            "LastName": "Bane",
            "HomeStateCode": "CA",
            "DirectorName": "N/A"
        }]
    }]
}
```

How can I parse this data in C# using the `JavaScriptSerializer()` class? It doesn't matter what is the data type being used to store the serialized data. I want it accessible easily enough to use it to be put into an excel file. What data type is the easiest to work with when dealing with excel?

This data will ultimately end up in an excel workbook, with each section of the JSON as different tabs.

Comment: Have you tried [json.net](//json.net)?

Comment: Take a look at [this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: @FrankerZ How do yo deserialize a string with json.net?

Comment: Google that exact question, and I'm sure the first result will be an example